# In AWS, How can i find if a given vpc id is a valid one using the aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli, amazon-vpc, jenkins-groovy

I'm using the following in my jenkins file

```
sh aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-ids ${VPC_ID} --query 'Vpcs[*].[State]' --output text
```

If it is valid is gives me `available`

else it gives me the error :

`An error occurred (InvalidVpcID.NotFound) when calling the DescribeVpcs operation: The vpc ID 'vpc-0xx0xx0xx' does not exist`

Is there a way to gracefully catch the response using this method ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use filter rather than --vpc-ids.

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filters Name=vpc-id,Values="id" --query 'Vpcs[*].[State]'
```

It will not give an error just empty.

Furthermore, this is my modified one. Since the vpc-id is unique, you don't need [*] when you set the vpc-id and just select the first one and no bracket for `state`.

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filters Name=vpc-id,Values="id" --query 'Vpcs[0].State'
```

Then, the result looks like

```
"avalilable"
```

or

```
null
```